# Event not firing for emulateTransitionEnd

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

When I run the code below with a too high `TRANSITION_DURATION`, the function never gets executed.

```
_el.height(_el[0].scrollHeight)
 .one(Util.TRANSITION_END, complete)
 .emulateTransitionEnd(TRANSITION_DURATION);
```

For example, when `TRANSITION_DURATION` is set to 350, the event never gets called. However when `TRANSITION_DURATION` is set to 1 the event occurs.

Struggling to understand the reasoning? Anyone understand this better?

For context of the code see below, the specific question regards the line right at the end of the `_show` function:

```js
MetisMenu.prototype._show = function _show(element) {
  if (this._transitioning || $(element).hasClass(this._config.collapsingClass)) {
    return;
  }
  var _this = this;
  var _el = $(element);

  var startEvent = $.Event(Event.SHOW);
  _el.trigger(startEvent);

  if (startEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    return;
  }

  _el.parent(this._config.parentTrigger).addClass(this._config.activeClass);

  if (this._config.toggle) {
    this._hide(_el.parent(this._config.parentTrigger).siblings().children(this._config.subMenu + '.' + this._config.collapseInClass).attr('aria-expanded', false));
  }

  _el.removeClass(this._config.collapseClass).addClass(this._config.collapsingClass).height(0);

  this.setTransitioning(true);

  var complete = function complete() {
    console.log("running complete")
    _el.removeClass(_this._config.collapsingClass).addClass(_this._config.collapseClass + ' ' + _this._config.collapseInClass).height('').attr('aria-expanded', true);

    _this.setTransitioning(false);

    _el.trigger(Event.SHOWN);
  };

  if (!Util.supportsTransitionEnd()) {
    complete();
    return;
  }
  _el.height(_el[0].scrollHeight).one(Util.TRANSITION_END, complete).emulateTransitionEnd(TRANSITION_DURATION);
};
```